# Divs wider than header and nav

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello i have just started to learn to code today and i decided to start with html and css.

I'm making and website template / layout using html css and bootstrap 4.

But i have run into a problem with my divs being wider than my header and navigation bar when not responsive and can't seem to work out why and was hoping maybe someone could tell me why.

[Image of my divs being wider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvFUI.png)

I'm also trying to float / angle two of the last links in the navigation bar to the right but they don't.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Hammersmith One", Hammersmith One, sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Hammersmith One", Hammersmith One, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 1em 10em;
  font-size: 0.8750em;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 222);
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

nav {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 149, 13);
  color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  ;
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hammersmith One" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h1>My Header</h1>
    <p>Text Here</p>
  </header>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item" style="float:right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" style="float:right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-center">Card Header</h5>
        <div class="card-body text-center">Card Body Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rightcolumn">
      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-center">Card Header</h5>
        <div class="card-body text-center">Card Body Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-center">Card Header</h5>
        <div class="card-body text-center">Card Body Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-center">Card Header</h5>
        <div class="card-body text-center">Card Body Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="container-fluid text-center fixed-bottom">
    <p><b>Footer Text</b></p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is due to the negative margins in the `.row` class.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Sorry to bother you but would you have any ideas why i my last two links in my nav bar don't float to the right?

Comment: Do you mean this kind of result? - https://ibb.co/1M3vQwv

Comment: Yeah that's what i was trying to achieve.

Comment: **1** - Add class `w-100` to ul with `navbar-nav` class. Like that - https://ibb.co/9b9v4Ck. **2** - Remove `float: right` out of every 4 and 5 `nav-item` class. That doesn't make sense. **3** - Add `margin-left: auto;` for the fourth `nav-item`. Like that - https://ibb.co/4fZB4gx.

Comment: But it will be better if you add `margin-left: auto;` through **css**, but not through the **style** attribute. In this case, it will be easier to override this style for mobile screens.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help.